# Replace line breaks with single space in C

Tags: c

I am not able to replace the line breaks in a file with a single space.
Say for example the file contains

> A book is a set or collection of written, printed, illustrated, or blank sheets, made of paper, parchment, or other various material.
>   Books may also refer to works of literature, or a main division of such a work. In library and information science, a book is called a monograph.
>   A store where books are bought and sold is a bookstore or bookshop. Books can also be borrowed from libraries.

There is a line break at the start of the sentence(A book is a set....) and again there is a line break before starting the next line(Books may also refer..)

I need this line break to replaced with a single space as follows

> A book is a set or collection of written, printed, illustrated, or blank sheets, made of paper, parchment, or other various material, usually fastened together to hinge at one side.Books may also refer to works of literature, or a main division of such a work. In library and information science, a book is called a monograph.A store where books are bought and sold is a bookstore or bookshop. Books can also be borrowed from libraries.

The contents will be in .csv file . At code level, I will be reading the file. So while reading the file using fgets how to hanle the line breaks. This is the way I would be reading the contents of the file.

```
int FileRead(char *inputfile)
{
    char buf[400]; 
    if ((fileinfo=fopen(inputfile,"r"))==NULL)


    /* read header row and ignore it */
    if (fgets(buf,400,fileinfo)!=NULL)
    {
        printf("read row");
        rowsread ++;
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(fileinfo);
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(buf,400,fileinfo)!=NULL)              /* read till EOF   */
    {
        rowsread ++;
        ............
        ............
        ............
```

Could anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: Is there a requirement to use c? How about using command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the file one character at a time and test for `'\n'` - if the character is not equal to `'\n'` then output it unmodified, otherwise replace it by a space.

Comment: I tried the following stuff.. by just changing \n wherever it is encountered into '@' (i gave @ just for testing purpose).But the entire content is getting replaced with '@' and i could just see '@' as the ouput instead of the original text.                     `int i;
  for (  i = 0; i< 400; ++i )
    {                                                         if ( buf[i] == '\n' || buf[i] == '\r' )
        {
            buf[i] = '@';
        }
    } `

Comment: @planet100: try stepping through your code in a debugger to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to replace newlines with spaces, the usual approach in C is significantly easier. But I can't see how the problem as you specified integrates with CSV formatted files (a complete example would be wonderful) -- so this might only serve as a partial answer.

The general rule is: read in a character. Inspect it. Do something with it:

```
int c;
FILE *f;

while((c=getc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (c=='\n') {
        putchar(' ');
    } else {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

For each special case, you add another `else if ()` block. (Or use a `switch`; all those `break` statements are distracting, though.)

Comment: @Paul, haha, too much Ruby lately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system, the line breaks may be:
`\r\n` in MS Windows
`\n` in Linux
and `\r` in Mac as I remembered.

Comment: If you open the file in text mode then you don't need to worry about this - all line endings will be `'\n'`. Also the comment about `\r` on the Mac dates back to "classic" Mac OS (pre 2000) - Mac OS X uses normal *nix line endings.